# How do I assign a static Ip address AND DNS settings *WITHOUT* DHCP?

Tags: raspbian

I manually set the IP and DNS settings using the Raspbian GUI and now cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the damn settings on the command line.

In the old days you just used NetworkManager but what on earth is Raspbian using to configure IP settings?

Answer (score 1):

OMG nvm for XXXXX sakes, they put the STATIC settings in the DHCP CLIENT.

For future reference, you have to change /etc/dhcpcd.conf and add/modify these lines:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.10
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.5
static domain_search=test.local
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are stored in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. At least that is where they are normally stored - I have never used the GUI to modify Static IP.

See [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)

PS `Raspbian` **DOES NOT** use `NetworkManager` and never has - current distributions use `dhcpcd`.